# DMA_SxCR Enable bit unable to be written on stm32f412

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32f4

I'm trying to start a DMA transfer on my stm32f412, and I've got everything set up to the point where I'm setting the control registers on the DMA channels/streams for TX and RX.  I am able to set the enable (Bit 0) on the TX, but not the RX.

The datasheet has 3 options for the bit being cleared by hardware: 1.) On a DMA end of transfer (stream ready to be configured) 2.) If a transfer error occurs on the AHB master buses 3.) When the FIFO threshold on memory AHB port is not compatible with the size of the burst.

I don't think it could be the first or the third, because the DMA transfer hasn't even started yet, and there isn't a burst configured, it's just a single transfer.  I'm not quite certain what the second means, but there aren't transfer errors marked in the error registers.

Any avenues to look into would be appreciated

Edit: Ugh, I was looking at the wrong registers for to find the DMA_LISR and _HISR.  There was a transfer error on my RX channel.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of DMA_SxCR_EN bit in the reference manual:

> Note: Before setting EN bit to '1' to start a new transfer, the event flags corresponding to the
>   stream in DMA_LISR or DMA_HISR register must be cleared.

In my experience, these event flags include not only the error flags, but also the regular event flags like *Transfer Complete* or *Half Transfer*. In some cases, I also ended up clearing FIFO error flag, although I can't remember the reason behind it.

This problem manifests itself as *"DMA works only once"*. In your case, it doesn't work even once, so there can be other problems. Still, I think it's worth trying to clear all the status flags before enabling the stream.

Comment: Oh damnit, I was looking at the wrong register for the DMA_LISR and HISR.  Clearing the channel statuses with the L/HIFCR was the solution, didn't even need to clear all of the errors.

Comment: It was a lot confusing for me when I tried to port some F0 & F1 code to F4 for the first time. F0 & F1 DMA works quite differently and I completely missed that *Note*.

Comment: Yup, the whole thing with the super specific SPI/DMA enabling order was just so frustrating.

Comment: I found this post but my problem was actually a bug in CubeMX. https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000Bmob3uSQA/dma-not-working-in-cubemx-generated-code-order-of-initialization